# PHP Image upload fails FTP connection

Tags: php, image, upload, ftp

I'm having some trouble debugging an *old* website. The original programmer is long out of touch, and I can't seem to find the error. The problem appears to be that when the user uploads an image, it never makes it to the ftp directory. The database values for description, file name, etc are made. Credentials are known good and tested.

I've done some looking and found a few scripts that do much the same thing; and it appears the PHP functions are all still valid (searched them at php.net). So I'm at a bit of a loss.

This script just stopped working two months ago. There was some DNS trouble with the server, but it was resolved and all seems well. Not sure if it's related.

If anyone can spot the problem I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
    <?php
IF($ResizeAuth != "yes" OR $ItemID2Resize == "") //This page will exit right here unless the Resize Authorization is set to yes, and the New Image variable has some value
{
  exit();
}

ini_set("memory_limit","24M"); //sets the total memory limit to 24 Megabytes just on this page for all of its scripts. The default is only 8M and fails with re-sizing large images.

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser-correct","dbpw-correct");
$db = mysql_select_db("databasename-correct",$connection);

$conn_id = ftp_connect("www.correct-domain.com"); 
ftp_login($conn_id, "workingftpusername", "workingftppassword") or die("Could not connect");    

FUNCTION uploadPic($src_img,$dDir,$maxWidth,$maxHeight,$resizeFlag,$tempName)
{

//destination
//(old) $dest = $dDir.$tempName;

//get source dimentions
$src_dims = getImageSize($src_img);

//create appropriate temp image
switch ($src_dims[2]) {
case 1: //GIF
break;

case 2: //JPEG
$srcImage = imageCreateFromJpeg($src_img);
break;

case 3: //PNG
break;

default:
return false;
break;
}

$srcRatio = $src_dims[0]/$src_dims[1]; // width/height ratio
$destRatio = $maxWidth/$maxHeight;

if ($destRatio > $srcRatio) {
$destSize[1] = $maxHeight;
$destSize[0] = $maxHeight*$srcRatio;
}
else {
$destSize[0] = $maxWidth;
$destSize[1] = $maxWidth/$srcRatio;
}

//if set image dimensions are required:
if ($resizeFlag == 1) {
$destSize[0] = $maxWidth;
$destSize[1] = $maxHeight;

}

$thumb_w = $destSize[0];
$thumb_h = $destSize[1];
$dst_img = imageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);
imageCopyResampled($dst_img,$srcImage,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$src_dims[0],$src_dims[1]);

switch ($src_dims[2]) {
case 1:
break;
case 2:
#(original) imageJpeg($dst_img, $dest, 75); //75 denotes image quality / compression ratio
$resizedimage = imageJpeg($dst_img, NULL, 75); //75 denotes image quality / compression ratio
break;

case 3:
break;
}
//$y++;
unlink($src_img);

return $resizedimage;

}

######################

$maxImageWidth = 640; //pixels
$maxThumbWidth = 131; //pixels

$ImageName = $ItemID2Resize."_temp1.jpg";
$ThumbName = $ItemID2Resize."_temp2.jpg";
$NewImageName = "Item".$ItemID2Resize.".jpg";
$NewThumbName = "Item".$ItemID2Resize."_thumb.jpg";

$TempImageFile = uploadPic("temp_image_resize/$ImageName","",$maxImageWidth,0,0,"");
$TempImageFile = fopen($TempImageFile,"r");

@ftp_delete($conn_id, "httpdocs/images/Items/$NewImageName"); //deletes the previous jpg referencing the same item if it exsists.
ftp_fput($conn_id, "httpdocs/images/Items/$NewImageName", $TempImageFile, FTP_BINARY);
fclose($TempImageFile);
#ftp_delete($conn_id, "httpdocs/mckadmin/temp_image_resize/$NewImageName");

$TempThumbFile = tmpfile();
uploadPic("temp_image_resize/$ThumbName","",$maxThumbWidth,0,0,$TempThumbFile);
fseek($TempThumbFile,0);
@ftp_delete($conn_id, "httpdocs/images/Items/$NewThumbName"); //deletes the previous jpg referencing the same item if it exsists.
ftp_fput($conn_id, "httpdocs/images/Items/$NewThumbName", $TempThumbFile, FTP_BINARY);
fclose($TempThumbFile);
#ftp_delete($conn_id, "httpdocs/mckadmin/temp_image_resize/$NewThumbName");

######################

$ImagePath4SQL = "http://www.mycopperkettle.com/images/Items/$NewImageName";
$ThumbPath4SQL = "http://www.mycopperkettle.com/images/Items/$NewThumbName";
$CheckExsistingq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product_ImagePaths WHERE ItemID=\"$ItemID2Resize\"");
$CheckExsisting = mysql_num_rows($CheckExsistingq);

IF($CheckExsisting == 0)
{
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO Product_ImagePaths (ItemID,ImagePath,ThumbPath) VALUES (\"$ItemID2Resize\",\"$ImagePath4SQL\",\"$ThumbPath4SQL\")");
}
ELSE
{
  mysql_query("UPDATE Product_ImagePaths SET ImagePath=\"$ImagePath4SQL\", ThumbPath=\"$ThumbPath4SQL\" WHERE ItemID=\"$ItemID2Resize\"");
}

ftp_close($conn_id); //close the FTP connection

?>
```

Thanks again!

~ Dr. Peril

Comment: Difficult to say what is wrong, as two month ago, your script use to work very well. May be this is not a script problem but a FTP problem. did the FTP change ? did the path of file change..?

Comment: far too many calls without any error checking, implying that the code simply assumes everything works perfectly, every time, and simply plows on ahead even as the whole thing goes up in flames.

Comment: don't use mysql_*, it is deprecated in PHP5.5.

Comment: @user1073122 : Agreed, it's difficult. FTP credentials work, I'm using them now. I've also just reset checked all the permissions :S

Comment: @MarcB : Indeed, any suggestions on tests? I'll echo out some vars after each step, we'll see what happens eh?

Comment: @Lior : Oops, I missed that one, thanks for the tip, I'll update the db code and report back :)